# Unable to run Kafka - getting no output in cmd and No such file or directory error in Git Bash

Tags: apache-kafka

I am setting up Kafka in my local. I have unzipped the 2.12 version and started zookeeper. Zookeeper is up and running but when I am trying to start kafka using the command `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties` , it is not showing any output.

I have also tried in git bash using the command `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties` , it is giving error as

> /c/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306:
>   C:\Program: No such file or directory.

Can you please help me with the solution.

Comment: Seem a quoting problem. Directory breaking in space.

Comment: Not showing any output maybe a phenomenon of running well.

Answer (score 13):

I use git bash on windows, and run the scripts in kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin (not kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin\windows).

Add double quotes around the JAVA term, in line 306.

```
exec "$JAVA" $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

If that does not help, add "set -x" at the top of the "kafka-run-class.sh" script to see the real problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
```

Comment: Adding double quotes around the JAVA term, in line 306 worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are unzipping kafka in a windows machine, I recommend you to run launch zookeeper and kafka server via windows cmd terminal...

Thus, please run both commands from the "windows" folder:

First, launch zookeeper:

```
C:\DevTools\kafka_2.12-2.4.1\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Then, kafka server:

```
C:\DevTools\kafka_2.12-2.4.1\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```

Important to mention that if you would use git bash on a windows machine to launch zookeeper and the kafka server you may face some errors regarding to the construction of the $CLASSPATH in "kafka-run-class":

```
$ ./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre1.8.0_151/lib;:/c/DevTools/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/c/DevTools/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/c/DevTools/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/c/DevTools/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/c/DevTools/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/
```

Therefore, the scripts wont be able to run the jars.

Documentation http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to line 306 and change `$CLASSPATH` to

```
cygpath -wp $CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to account for `$CLASSPATH` having Windows-like entries.

My "Solution" was to simply set `CLASSPATH=""` at the beginning of `bin/kafka-run-class.sh`:

```
# MINGW64 if Git Bash is detected.
if [[ $(uname -a) =~ "MINGW64" ]]; then
  CLASSPATH=""
fi
```

For reference, my `CLASSPATH` was set to like:

```
.;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar; #etc..
```

After removing those "C:" entries separated by `;`, the class was found and command worked.